# error overiding save method while extending Django-registration app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration, django-1.3

I am using django-registration app.  and have following code in forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile
from pprint import pprint


class UserRegistrationForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):
    #email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    fullname = forms.CharField(label = "Full name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("fullname", "email", )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.userprofile.full_name = self.cleaned_data["fullname"]
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I inherited from Django-registraion app's class RegistrationFormUniqueEmail so I when called save method at `user = super(UserRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)` it says, that save attribute doesnot exist. I actually wrote this code with inheritance from `UserCreationForm` . 
I have just read the comment for SuperClass of RegistrationFormUniqueEmail  that is :

```
   """
Form for registering a new user account.

Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
registration backend.

"""
```

These comments ask to not define another save method but I need to. So is there way that I can do define save method and call parent save method too to define additional fields? Following is the code of django-registration apps's forms.py:

```
    """
Forms and validation code for user registration.

"""


from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


# I put this on all required fields, because it's easier to pick up
# on them with CSS or JavaScript if they have a class of "required"
# in the HTML. Your mileage may vary. If/when Django ticket #3515
# lands in trunk, this will no longer be necessary.
attrs_dict = {'class': 'required'}


class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    """
    Form for registering a new user account.

    Validates that the requested username is not already in use, and
    requires the password to be entered twice to catch typos.

    Subclasses should feel free to add any additional validation they
    need, but should avoid defining a ``save()`` method -- the actual
    saving of collected user data is delegated to the active
    registration backend.

    """
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                                label=_("Username"),
                                error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,
                                                               maxlength=75)),
                             label=_("E-mail"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_("Password (again)"))

    def clean_username(self):
        """
        Validate that the username is alphanumeric and is not already
        in use.

        """
        existing = User.objects.filter(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        if existing.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']

    def clean(self):
        """
        Verifiy that the values entered into the two password fields
        match. Note that an error here will end up in
        ``non_field_errors()`` because it doesn't apply to a single
        field.

        """
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return self.cleaned_data


class RegistrationFormTermsOfService(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which adds a required checkbox
    for agreeing to a site's Terms of Service.

    """
    tos = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                             label=_(u'I have read and agree to the Terms of Service'),
                             error_messages={'required': _("You must agree to the terms to register")})


class RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which enforces uniqueness of
    email addresses.

    """
    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the
        site.

        """
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']


class RegistrationFormNoFreeEmail(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which disallows registration with
    email addresses from popular free webmail services; moderately
    useful for preventing automated spam registrations.

    To change the list of banned domains, subclass this form and
    override the attribute ``bad_domains``.

    """
    bad_domains = ['aim.com', 'aol.com', 'email.com', 'gmail.com',
                   'googlemail.com', 'hotmail.com', 'hushmail.com',
                   'msn.com', 'mail.ru', 'mailinator.com', 'live.com',
                   'yahoo.com']

    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Check the supplied email address against a list of known free
        webmail domains.

        """
        email_domain = self.cleaned_data['email'].split('@')[1]
        if email_domain in self.bad_domains:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Registration using free email addresses is prohibited. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

I just want to know that how can I override save() method or else how can I create new additional fields?

Comment: tried importing just RegistrationForm?

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain I am importing and using this `from registration.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` and also inheriting from `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` and in their file's comments they ask to avoid defining save() , while if I don't define save(), then how can I add more fields to my UserRegistrationForm?  I have also imported registrationForm using `from registration.forms import RegistrationForm` but still error is `super' object has no attribute 'save'`

Comment: Try deleting that def __init__

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain Although I need that for not having username field, but I delete that for a moment but it didn't solve the problem. Same error exist. Also please note that problem happen when I submit form.

Comment: and you also un-commentted email as well right?

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain Commented email has no work to do as it is already in parent class, thats why I commented it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10626/discussion-between-hafiz-and-frantzdy-romain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution of my own posted problem:

I have removed that django-registration app's RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, and instead I am inheriting from UserCreationForm and added the required method into my own UserRegistrationForm so I am able to override save method and able to do the things that I wanted to .